# visual studio 2015 The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sccm

Visual Studio 2015 on windows 10 64-bit with target set to 32-bit.

Trying to build the CustomTSActionControl sample from the System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK

After referencing all the DLLs ok when I try to build it fails with:

```
------ Build started: Project: CustomTSActionControl, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  CustomTSActionControl -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\CustomTSActionControl.dll
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: The command "copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.Common.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\AdminUI.Common.dll"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.Controls.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\AdminUI.Controls.dll"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.DialogFoundation.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\AdminUI.DialogFoundation.dll"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.OsdCommon.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\AdminUI.OsdCommon.dll"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.TaskSequenceEditor.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\AdminUI.TaskSequenceEditor.dll"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.DialogFramework.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.DialogFramework.dll"" exited with code 1.`
```

This is weird to me since VS accepted all the refernces to those various DLLs when adding them. I've tried adding

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\R2\AdminConsole\bin\

and

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager SDK\Samples\Admin UI\CustomTaskSequenceAction\VCSharp.Net\bin\x86\Debug\

to the Reference Paths but same result. I'm guessing it needs quotes around the paths because of the spaces but I'm niot sure where to put those quotes as I don't know where VS has these paths stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open Project\CustomTSAControl Properties...
click "Build Evdents"
click "Edit Post-Build ..."

replace

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.Common.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.Common.dll"
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.Controls.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.Controls.dll"
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.DialogFoundation.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.DialogFoundation.dll"
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.OsdCommon.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.OsdCommon.dll"
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\AdminUI.TaskSequenceEditor.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.TaskSequenceEditor.dll"
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe"
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll"
copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.DialogFramework.dll" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.DialogFramework.dll"
```

with (in my case the DLLs were at  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin )

```
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\AdminUI.Common.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.Common.dll"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\AdminUI.Controls.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.Controls.dll"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\AdminUI.DialogFoundation.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.DialogFoundation.dll"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\AdminUI.OsdCommon.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.OsdCommon.dll"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\AdminUI.TaskSequenceEditor.dll" "$(TargetDir)AdminUI.TaskSequenceEditor.dll"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.DialogFramework.dll" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.DialogFramework.dll"
```

and then it builds as expected. 
No clue why Visual Studio put  those bad paths in there when it knew when I made the references where they were. May have been a vestige from the original references that came with the sample.